# How to translate rolling function in Python to PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to replicate the following Python code:

```
df_act['steps_ma'] = df_act['steps'].rolling(5).mean()
```

what the code is supposed to do is to calculate the mean of the column stemps_ma, the mean has to be calculated using the current row and the 4 rows prior. So for example if we are looking at row number 10, the mean would have to be calculated with the values of steps_ma for columns 10,9,8,7,6.
to Pyspark, but the only info I am getting is with columns of timestamp, while my column "steps" is a column of integers.

I am going back and forth with this approach but I am getting so many errors:

```
winSpec = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(-(5), 0)
df_act.withColumn('steps_ma', mean('steps').over(winSpec)).show()
```

Comment: Please share the error details! Additionally, it will be great if you could share sample of your input and expected output datasets. This is will help understanding your use case in a much better way.

Comment: We do not know what is inside the mysterious variable MA. It's hard to help...

Comment: changed it, so sorry!

Comment: Please share your sample input and expected output